# insert new objects in javascript at correct position sorted by timestamp

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I try to add an object to an array on the correct position by timestamp, but the first object is always the last in the list after sorting (which makes sense if you look at the sorting algorithm).

This is the array I want to sort

```
const arr = [
  { tstmp: "2022-12-13T10:36:35.164165+0100", name: "c" },
  { tstmp: "2022-12-13T10:18:33.798261+0100", name: "b" },
  { tstmp: "2022-12-14T12:54:50.109871+0100", name: "a" },
  { tstmp: "2022-12-13T10:18:36.161500+0100", name: "d" },
  { tstmp: "2022-12-13T10:36:30.584337+0100", name: "e" },
  { tstmp: "2022-12-14T13:07:23.681388+0100", name: "f" },
  { tstmp: "2022-12-14T16:07:23.681388+0100", name: "g" },
];
```

This is the sorting function

```
const insertItem = (newItem) => {
  if (end.length === 0) {
    end.push(newItem);
    return;
  }
  const x = end.findIndex((x) => new Date(x.tstmp) > new Date(newItem.tstmp));
  end.splice(x, 0, newItem);
  return;
};
```

This is how I use the function

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  const item = arr[i];
  insertItem(item);
}
console.log(end);
```

This is the Output

```
{ tstmp: '2022-12-13T10:18:33.798261+0100', name: 'b' },
 { tstmp: '2022-12-13T10:18:36.161500+0100', name: 'd' },
 { tstmp: '2022-12-13T10:36:30.584337+0100', name: 'e' },
 { tstmp: '2022-12-14T12:54:50.109871+0100', name: 'a' },  
 { tstmp: '2022-12-14T13:07:23.681388+0100', name: 'f' },
 { tstmp: '2022-12-14T16:07:23.681388+0100', name: 'g' },
 { tstmp: '2022-12-13T10:36:35.164165+0100', name: 'c' },
```

The output is perfect besides the "c"

Answer (score 0):

I believe that (unless you have many *many* items in the array) it may be more convenient to simply `sort` the array once all the items have been `push`ed to it:

```js
const arr = [
  { tstmp: "2022-12-13T10:36:35.164165+0100", name: "c" },
  { tstmp: "2022-12-13T10:18:33.798261+0100", name: "b" },
  { tstmp: "2022-12-14T12:54:50.109871+0100", name: "a" },
  { tstmp: "2022-12-13T10:18:36.161500+0100", name: "d" },
  { tstmp: "2022-12-13T10:36:30.584337+0100", name: "e" },
  { tstmp: "2022-12-14T13:07:23.681388+0100", name: "f" },
  { tstmp: "2022-12-14T16:07:23.681388+0100", name: "g" },
].sort((a, b) => new Date(a.tstmp) - new Date(b.tstmp))

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: The problem is, that I have an raay (in Redux) which is changing a lot. there are functional components (in react) related to it which are rendering always the current state. So the best way  would be the new objects instantly insert on the correct position for me. This for loop is just a simulation

Comment: in that case, `sort` the array inside the reducer to give the new state it's correct order